# Humanoid robot rig- foot issue: Either the foot goes through the ground, or is disconnected from the leg

Tags: rigging, bones

So have this humanoid robot leg that I made, and I wanted to rig it. So I made the bones, and the IK constraint. Somewhat expectedly, the foot goes through the ground when I move the hips bone. I tried to fix it by parenting the foot bone to the IK bone. However, that disconnected the foot from the rest of the leg.
I feel like it's probably a parenting issue, or maybe just that the ankle only rotate on one axis. I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to deal with it.

Blend file- [image]

[image: 1- Foot goes through the ground]

[image: 2- Foot disconnect from the leg]

Comment: hello could you please share your file, at least the armature?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=lGOk1p8K" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/lGOk1p8K/)

Comment: Have you tried to parent the foot to the Bone_IK_Target, then parent Bone_IK_Target, Bone_IK_Pole and the spine bone to the root?

Comment: and if you want to attach the foot to the shin, give the foot a Copy Location constraint with the shin as target, put the Head/Tail value at 1

Comment: I assume by Spine you mean the Hips. I tried parenting those bones to the root, and also tried both copy location, but that didn't help either.

Comment: see my rigging here, what is the problem with this setting? https://zupimages.net/up/22/28/m1dr.gif

Comment: 1- The root bone, from my understanding, is only to place the rig in the scene.
2- You are manipulating it only on 1 Axis, in the side view. When I do it in the 3D view, I get this- https://i.ibb.co/9YLvJ31/Screenshot-1.jpg

Essentially I want to leg to be parallel to the hips. Currently it's not possible with the IK setup- https://i.ibb.co/c6c3N6Y/Screenshot-2.jpg
But it's doable with the FK setup.

Comment: The root bone is the master bone, all the parent bones (like spine bone) and all the controller bones (like IK target bones and IK pole target bones) should be parented to it. As for your picture, I'm not sure what's the problem, could you please elaborate?

Comment: The foot is disconnected from the shin. It is no longer part of the leg. It looks like it broke off from the leg. It looks fine in the side view, when you move the IK up and down, or front to back, but side to side is clearly an issue.
https://i.ibb.co/P5LhV5R/Screenshot-3.jpg

Comment: that's why if you parent (with keep offset option) the foot to Bone_IK_Target you'll easily be able to control and rotate the foot the way you want: https://zupimages.net/up/22/28/w1ry.gif

Comment: That is what happened WHEN I parented the foot to Bone_IK_Target. It lost the rotation of the Shin. Rotating the foot might work in a human rig, where the ankle can rotate on multiple axis. But in this robotic leg it can only be rotate on 1 axis. I can try to manually align it every time, but that will not be as accurate.

Comment: So you want the foot to stay aligned with the shin and be able to rotate it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137692/discussion-between-yogev-and-moonboots).

Comment: I'm not sure there's any solution here, because you want your foot object to sometimes inherit the rotation of the shin, and sometimes not, maybe you should use my first solution (parent the foot bone to the controller) and correct its alignment to the shin manually? I hope someone will propose a solution though...